# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count

Tags: mysql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS preventive_maintenance;

-- create table
CREATE TABLE `preventive_maintenance` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_type` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `device_serial` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `error_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `resolutiom` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `preventive_maintenance`
    (`device_type`,`device_serial`,`customer_name`,`error_code`,`resolutiom`,`timestamp`)
VALUES
    ('a1','02598352','Dr. Wonda','35','Power','Over Heat',now());
```

I get

```
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count
```

Comment: This is because `Column count doesn't match value count` in your statement's columns and values sections.

Comment: Your `INSERT` has 6 columns, and 7 values...

Answer (score 0):

Your value columns are more than your insertion column - it would be 6 for both

```
INSERT INTO `preventive_maintenance`
    (`device_type`,`device_serial`,`customer_name`,`error_code`,`resolutiom`,`timestamp`)
VALUES
    ('a1','02598352','Dr. Wonda','Power','Over Heat',now());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more values in your INSERT query than the columns you have specified.

6 columns :

`(`device_type`,`device_serial`,`customer_name`,`error_code`,`resolutiom`,`timestamp`)`

but 7 VALUES:

`('a1','02598352','Dr. Wonda','35','Power','Over Heat',now());`